# Manually force trigger a change event on select in nested form using stimulusjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs

Using Haml, ruby 2.7.2, rails 6.1.2.1, stimulus ^2.0.0

So, I am using a nested form that shows a *select* type. Based on the value of the *select* type, I will either show or hide a *div*. I'm converting my coffeescript to stimulus, and I'm not sure how to force trigger a change event, or instead just run the code that checks the value of the *select* to decide if I should hide or show the *div*. In the past, Inside my html.haml view I would call this:

```
:javascript
  $('select.answer_type').change()
```

Based on another post in here: https://discuss.hotwire.dev/t/triggering-turbo-frame-with-js/1622, I tried to change it to say:

```
:javascript
  q_typeTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

And that didn't work. Maybe there is another way to do this, or I'm using the wrong vocabulary to look up the example I want to do?  I'd rather just manually execute the Controller#action and give it the *select* object to work off of right away, but I'm not sure how to do this in html/*script* tag. Thanks for any help!

Here is my relevant code that should help:
`_question_fields.html.haml`

```
.nested-fields.question
  .form_group.grid-x
    .fields.cell.shrink
      = f.select :answer_type, 
                 options_for_select(["String","Option","Checkbox"],
                 f.object.answer_type),{}, 
                 class: 'answer_type', 
                 data: {nested_form_target: 'q_type', 
                        action: 'nested-form#update_q_type'}

    .cell.answers_group{ style: 'visibility: hidden; display: none'}
      = render partial: 'answers', locals: { f: f, q_level: q_level }

:javascript
  q_typeTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

`nested_form_controller.js`

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["q_type", "answers"]

  update_q_type(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('You have selected ' + this.q_type )

    let d_question = event.target.closest(".question")
    let d_select   = d_question.querySelector("select")
    let d_answer   = d_question.querySelector(".answers_group")

    console.log('Select: ' + d_select.value )

    switch(d_select.value) {
      case 'Option':
      case 'Checkbox':
        console.log(' Show Answers ')
        d_answer.style.visibility = "visible"
        d_answer.style.display = null
        return

      default:
        console.log(' Hide Answers ')
        d_answer.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        d_answer.style.display = 'none'
        return
    }

}
```

Here is an example .gif of the nested forms, shown below:

1. I add a Question
2. I select an *option* from the *select* tag, which triggers the select → change event: `nested-form#update_q_type`
3. If I select either **Option** or **Checkbox**, then I show the *div*, otherwise I hide the *div*

[image]

Now, here is why I'm trying to trigger the select → change event. If I start to ***edit*** this record again, it loads the data just fine. However, it does not know when to show the answers *div* or not. That's why I need to trigger the select → change event so that it can properly set up the answers *div* to either hide or show. Otherwise, it's defaulted to always 'hide'.

I have another .gif below. As you can see, it loads the select with **Option** selected. if I try to select **Option** again, it doesn't do anything...because it hasn't really changed. If I change it to **Checkbox**, it of course updates. So basically, I need to do this onLoad, you can say.

[image]

Maybe there is a different way to do this? Thank you for your help!

***Update:*** I didn't realize my html tags were being interpreted as html. Oops. Changed all tags to italicized words. Ex: '/</select/>/' is now just *select*. Also I expanded on the question for more clarification.

Comment: So the problem is that on edit you need the `update_q_type` method to run on your select?

Comment: @sam, yes that is correct! I would think this would be as easy as just calling the method, but I haven't figured out how to do this via stimulusjs.

Answer (score 0):

StimulusJS has an initialize function that essentially runs when the page loads. You would use that for this purpose. The only other issue here is that you're passing in an event to `update_q_type` and you won't have an event on `initialize`. So what I find works is to extract most of the code to a separate function that my initialize and click function can both call. This helps you keep your code DRY.

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["q_type", "answers"]

  initialize() {
    this.switch(this.q_typeTarget)
  }

  update_q_type(event) {
    event.preventDefault
    this.switch(this.q_typeTarget)
  }

  switch(q_type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

One thing to note, it's not clear if you have one stimulus controller running here or one for every select box combo. You could do the 2nd and not have to use the `closest` method. It's meant to be very modular.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in replying. This is a nested form, so I could have 0, 1, or many select boxes, it's dynamic. Using the closest method is essential. 
I'm sorry to say that the Initialize didn't work for me. It didn't break the existing functionality, but it still didn't fix the onload. Thank you for the idea.